# Avoid opening Email client when send email Android

Tags: email, android-intent, email-client

I have an ordinary code to send text email via Intent, using the emulator.
The problem I have is that the 'Compose' activity of the Email client - I use an ICS AVD - comes-up when the startActivity() is executed. All the fields are correctly filled-in and I must click on 'Send' to wrap-up the process. After that, the control goes back to my application UI and the email is correctly delivered to destination.
What should I do to have done the sending smoothly in the background, without popping-up the emulator's Email application?
Here is my code:

```
public class AppPilot extends Application {
    ...
    private static Context context;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
    }
    ....
        /**
     * Send an Email 
     * @param emailAddress
     * @param emailObject
     * @param emailBody
     */
    public static void sendEmailCoupon(String emailAddress, String emailSubject,
        String  emailBody)  {

        String emailadd[] = { emailAddress };
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailadd);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);
        context.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer for those looking for in the future, in case this post will be clicked before the original one: [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a).
Basically, first download the 3 jar files - mail.jar (URI: http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/mail.jar);  activation.jar (URI: http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/activation.jar); additional.jar (URI: http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/additionnal.jar) into the /libs folder of your Eclipse project. Then right click on each of them and reference with Build Path > Add to Build Path.
Create a separate 'Email' class and follow at 100% the code as posted in the link above by 'droopie'.
Using JavaMail is required so that to bypass the security design principles or Android as an application container.
HTH